# Sorting x-axis in Seaborn / Matplotlib doesn't work

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to use py.sorted() func to sort the x-axis ("size") in reverse order, despite setting "reverse=True", it doesn't impact the plot, the axis is still in normal order. I wonder what I did wrong ... thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import seaborn.objects as so
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

df = pd.DataFrame(data=tips)

unique_xs = sorted(df["size"].unique(), reverse=True)

f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 2.4))

sns.violinplot(data=df, x="size", y="tip", ax=ax[0])
sns.lineplot(data=df, x=df["size"].map(unique_xs.index), y="tip", ax=ax[0])

for _, spine in ax[0].spines.items():
    spine.set_visible(True)
    spine.set_linewidth(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution, by adding "order=unique_xs" condition, the axis is reversed!

```
sns.violinplot(data=df, x="size", y="tip", ax=ax[0], order=unique_xs)
```